# Cross Browser CSS

Tags: css

Hi everyone for the past 6 months I have been practising on creating websites with XHTML/CSS/Javascript/jQuery

I've learned alot and I'm pretty confident on my skills, my only problem is that my CSS dosen't work cross-browser on older browsers especially in internet explorer 6 and 7.

So what I want to know is if anyone can recommend me some books or resources that can help me to create cross browser CSS?

Comment: It's almost 2012 ! Why learn how to code for IE6 while you can learn HTML5 and CSS3 ?

Comment: @Pierre Upvoted for speaking the truth!

Comment: I would love not to have to create CSS code for internet explorer 6 and 7 but I was asked by a client to create a website that needs to work even on those browsers so I have no choice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this claims to be [the ultimate guide to techniques for cross browser css](http://www.kashit.org/design/css/ultimate-guide-to-techniques-for-cross-browser-css/), so *should* have some useful information for you.

just found another useful link too [the principles of cross browser coding in css](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/06/07/the-principles-of-cross-browser-css-coding/)

Answer (score 2):

http://www.edgeofmyseat.com/blog/all/developing-css-for-ie6-and-7

Read this, it goes through pretty much the in's and out's of it. The best resource you'll ever need is Google, and use a reset css. Which is here:
http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: +1 for 'The best resource you'll ever need is Google' ;)